# AWS CLI config file vs. credentials file

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I understand the AWS CLI can make use of the `config` and `credentials` files for storing it's local profile configurations.

Does anyone know of any general guidance and or best practice with regards to what should go in each file?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

The AWS documentation which covers the two files can be found under [Configuration and Credential Files](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-config-files.html?shortFooter=true) in the AWS CLI documentation.

To summarise:

- The two files are distinct in order to enable the separation of credentials from less sensitive configuration information.
- The `credentials` file is intended for storing just credential information for the configured profiles. (Currently limited to: `aws_access_key_id`, `aws_secret_access_key` and `aws_session_token`)
- The `config` file is intended for storing non-sensitive configuration options for the configured profiles.
- The `config` file can also be configured to contain any information which could also be stored in the `credentials` file.
- In the case of conflicting credential information being specified for a profile in the `config` and `credentials` file, those in the `credentials` file will take precedence.

Comment: Bullet 2 is potentially misleading: region and output are stored in the config file (alone), not the credentials file.

Comment: @jarmod You are correct. I misunderstood the AWS documentation linked in my answer. I have edited my answer to remove those entries.