# How can I get AWS CLI to recognize my config file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I'm trying to spin up a s3 bucket via the AWS CLI and I'm getting the error "upload failed: .\mylocalfile.txt to s3://testBucket/mylocalfile.txt Unable to locate credentials".

I've ran aws configure and aws configure set on a default profile and i've done aws configure on a specific profile as well. In either case when I run AWS configure list I get the following

```
 Name                    Value             Type    Location
      ----                    -----             ----    --------
   profile              TestProfile           manual    --profile
access_key                <not set>             None    None
secret_key                <not set>             None    None
    region                us-east-1      config-file    ~/.aws/config
```

the secret key is set in the same config file as the region but they are being located for some reason.

When I run AWS configure list --profile TestProfile I expect the credentials set in AWS configure to appear properly.

Comment: OK, what output do you get when using `aws configure list --profile TestProfile`? Are you actually using `--profile TestProfile` when copying? Also, see [AWS CLI config file vs. credentials file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47096198/aws-cli-config-file-vs-credentials-file).

Comment: "the secret key is set in the same config file as the region", Normally, the credentials go in a file called "credentials", and the other settings, like region, go in a file called "config".